# API to retrieve total iOS rating from app store?

Tags: ios, http

I can retrieve recent iOS reviews like this:

```
fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/${IOS_LANG_CODE}/rss/customerreviews/id=${IOS_ID}/sortBy=mostRecent/json`)
```

However, I could not find any endpoint to retrieve the overall rating of an app in the appstore.(overall rating = the one you see big in the app store, not the single ratings). Also I can not find any official documentation from apple on this topic. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I might be very late to answer this but YES there is an absolutely free way to get the rating of the application. You can use

`http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=<app_id>`

to get a JSON with all the basic info related to your application. The key that you are looking for is `averageUserRating`. This will return a Double value and indicate the exact current iOS Rating.

To quickly check a sample, have a look at the details of the Amazon app(com.amazon.Amazon)
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=297606951

Comment: This works great for iOS apps, but does not seem to work for macOS apps. Rating is always 0 like for https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=1575557335 Any idea how to get those ratings?

BTW as demonstrated in this URL it is possible to prefix the country code to get specific results.

Comment: @Holtwick, yes for change your country code from `us` to `in` to get results for Indian App Store, for UK change it to `uk` and so on.
Once you change it to your own app Store, you will get correct ratings and not 0 everytime.

Comment: Thanks @kunal-gupta In my case it does not work with Mac App Store (not iOS). For example, this is my app PDFify. It has ratings in the German App store, but they don't show up under this link https://itunes.apple.com/de/lookup?id=1435055351 I guess the feature is iOS apps only.

Comment: Is there a way to get the individual ratings numbers?  This rss feed returns only the ratings that include a review, but I also want all the ratings that DO NOT include reviews.