# How to get the total number of ratings from Apple App Store API?

Tags: ios, api, app-store

I am trying to count the total number of ratings an app has in the Apple app store. I keep coming across this api call:

`https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=MY_ID/sortBy=mostRecent/json`

However this only returns 36 reviews and I can see on the App Store that there are 900+ reviews for this particular app. Does anyone know how I can view ALL of the app ratings or a total number and the average star rating?

Comment: Have you checked the following post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296782/api-to-retrieve-total-ios-rating-from-app-store

Comment: Yes, thank you @nopassport1 but I was hoping to use Apple's API not AppFigures

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way