# How to download apps review and ratings from itunes connect or appstore connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

what is the best way to download all apps reviews and ratings for apple app from app store/itunes connect.
any api available for the app reviews and ratings download as json or file?

thanks
Sundar

Comment: needs more context, as in download it to where? e.g. to show in a Slack channel, to populate a database? a website? to display within your iOS app?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann  download as file and populate in database.

Answer (score 5):

I did some research for you and found related questions that will provide you the answers you need to get to where you want to be, including:

[API to retrieve total iOS rating from app store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52296782/981049)
and [API to monitor iphone app store reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1090282/981049)

So to get reviews for Amazon's app, you can type this in at your browser search bar:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=297606951/sortBy=mostRecent/json

Comment: thanks Michael. do you have api for downloading all data rather than mostRecent json data.?

Comment: good question and I don't have the easy answer to it. I don't think Apple would want to make it trivial to get all reviews because some apps can have tens of thousands of reviews, so you'd need to get a page of reviews at a time, and according to [this link on discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6882459) from 2015, there may be a page limit of 10 pages of review data you can fetch.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have gone through apple.com discussion. But I didn't get the full data load solution.